# Add custom field to certificate

Tags: certificates, openssl

Is there a standard way of adding 
a custom data field, in my case a *mac address*, to a certificate. I sign them myself and they are used in a closed environment.

What I would like is a mechanism so that I can specify the 
mac address parameter via the commandline when calling "openssl req...",
maybe using the "-subj" line.

- Is it possible to write the openssl.cnf in such a way that 
  a new field is added in the extensions section that can be 
  set via the commandline option. I.e. if the fieldname is
  "**mac**" then via  `-subj ".../mac=0x023445344556..."` or some other commandline switch.

Or is there some other way i.e. via environment variables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom attributes to certificates, assuming you are using x509v3.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241703/openssl-custom-attribute-during-creation#31381163) provides the basics, which is that you need to use a config file, and create an actual attribute.

Your example is adding a field to the DN, which is a different thing.

Comment: If I only have one openssl.cnf and define a new OID field, how can I set the value when generating different cert requests: Is there an option to fetch it from the enviroment or via commandline switch?

Comment: Sorry, I think I found how to get the parameters from the enviromnent variables: ${ENV::name}...