# How can I create a self-signed certificate with a custom field?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

For experiment, I want to add a custom field in a TLS certificate then validate it. Because it is experiment, it will be a self-signed certificate. I use OpenSSL 1.1.0g and Ubunut 18.04. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: How do you define "Custom Field"?  Different x.509 tags in the CN?  Recognized SAN entry types?  Novel roll-your-own SAN entry types?

Comment: Yes. My own new field that I will give it a name and it stores a sting value.

Comment: check this answer https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/155670/add-custom-field-to-certificate